# Different ways to get the IP address from a Linux box

Tags: linux

I'm curious and I want to know all different methods for getting the IP address from a Linux box, I know `ifconfig` works well, but wondering if there are any other methods to use to obtain the ip address?

Comment: ifconfig is actually deprecated, and is replaced with the "ip" command. However many people (myself included) haven't quite got to grips with "ip" yet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be:

```
ip address list
```

Comment: or just 'ip addr'

Answer (score 4):

To find the external IP of a box (behind a NAT firewall for instance) try this one-liner:

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

So useful and so quick!

Answer (score 3):

The *ip* tool is quite handy and can give you a bunch of methods for IP address determination and much more.

Quick exmaples:

```
ip addr show dev wlan0
ip route list | grep -w src | awk '{print "device:",$3, "address:",$9}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used

```
hostname -i
```

But honestly I shouldn't because this relies on the /etc/hosts file of the machine and not the actual IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ping if you know the network interface. (eth0, eth1, wlan0, etc.)

> **ping -I eth0 www.google.com**
>   ping [-I interface]

from 10.1.1.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following command will list all IP addresses

```
ip addr show
```

The output from ifconfig does not always show secondary addresses on interfaces which do not have a named alias, such as those added by "ip addr add"